# How android tokenize contact name into fields

Tags: android, contacts

In my application i required all fields of contact. But device tokenize name differently. Like if i enter Mr or Prof test contact it will tokenize as Mr or Prof as prefix , test as first and contact as last name. But if i enter Mr & Mrs test contact it tokenize it as Mr as prefix , & Mrs as first name , test as middle name and contact as last name. In this case if i use first name in my app this produced some abnormal behavior. I have two questions :

- Is this android bug or user error?
- How user select prefix from name , it seems like android have list of names which can be categorize as prefix like Mr , Prof. Can anyone have this list ?

following is image of my device contact. [image]

Comment: your question is not easy to understand

Comment: Perhaps you can show how you are parsing it now, which is not working as desired.

Comment: The issue is not in my code , i am getting this data from android device. @steveenzoleko , my question is android device separate MR Test Contacts and Mr & Mrs Test contacts into fields differently. Why is this so ??? Is this an issue or android let user to put contacts into device by his/her self. If you have time go to contacts and create contact MR Test Contacts and then edit and open detail you will see all data in fields correctly but not in case when you make contact with Mr & Mrs Test Contact.

Comment: I just don't understand your problem. what was you expecting exactly? And in your picture the first field is your contact name and the other fields are phonetic names of the contact(they are intented for Voice Actions)